# Jsoup didnt shows the <tbody> content

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm using jsoup 1.8.3 to parse the html page and extract the data. This is the html page I'm trying to parse [CONTENT.](http://www.numberfire.com/nfl/teams/power-rankings/) But it doesn't display the  content. How can I achieve this?

This the code I tried,

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.numberfire.com/nfl/teams/power-rankings/")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36")
                .timeout(0).followRedirects(true).execute().parse();;
Elements table = doc.select("table");
Elements rows = table.select("tr");
System.out.print("============ "+table.html().toString());
```

And this is the output I got,

```
============ <thead> 
<tr valign="middle"> 
  <th rowspan="2" colspan="3" class="tal">Team</th> 
  <th rowspan="2" class="sep">Rec</th> 
  <th rowspan="2" class="col-proj_w"><a href="#" class="sorter" rel="proj_w">Proj</a></th> 
  <th rowspan="2" class="col-playoffs"><a href="#" class="sorter" rel="playoffs">Playoff</a></th> 
  <th rowspan="2" class="col-division"><a href="#" class="sorter" rel="division">Div</a></th> 
  <th rowspan="2" class="col-superbowl"><a href="#" class="sorter" rel="superbowl">SB</a></th> 
  <th class="sep" colspan="3">Offense</th> 
  <th class="sep" colspan="3">Defense</th> 
  <th rowspan="2" class="sep col-nerd"><a href="#" class="sorter" rel="nerd">nERD</a></th> 
 </tr> 
 <tr valign="middle"> 
  <th class="sep col-offense"><a href="#" class="sorter" rel="offense">Ovr</a></th> 
  <th class="col-o_rushing"><a href="#" class="sorter" rel="o_rushing">Rush</a></th> 
  <th class="col-o_passing"><a href="#" class="sorter" rel="o_passing">Pass</a></th> 
  <th class="sep col-defense"><a href="#" class="sorter" rel="defense">Ovr</a></th> 
  <th class="col-d_rushing"><a href="#" class="sorter" rel="d_rushing">Rush</a></th> 
  <th class="col-d_passing"><a href="#" class="sorter" rel="d_passing">Pass</a></th> 
 </tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody id="team-data"></tbody>
```

In here I didn't get the tbody content. Also I tried this way too.

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.numberfire.com/nfl/teams/power-rankings/").get();
```

Comment: which table to you want to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tbody is empty because most likely the webpage is dynamically populated.

A simple option is to use the save_as feature of most browsers to download the raw HTML locally and JSOUP the local file.